# LINQ Query Incorrect Results Using AND and AND OR

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I have a linq query which is pulling in the wrong results. My guess is that it's doing this because I'm missing a bracket or something or another.

```
var CurrentlyActiveIncidents = from b in db.Logs 
    join dc in db.Incidents 
    on b.LogID equals dc.LogID 
    where b.DateTimeResolved == null && 
        (dc.AssignedTechnician != null  || 
        dc.AssignedTechnician != CurrentUser)
```

I want all the incidents where the `datetimeresolved == null` and the assigned technician isn't null or is not assigned to the current user. At the moment the query is ignoring the `!= currentuser` part and I don't know why?

Comment: ignoring how?  What records are you getting that you shouldn't, or not getting that you should?

Comment: Are you sure you want the `||` and not the `&&`?

Comment: Unless `CurrentUser` is `null`, surely the assigned technician will *always* be either "not the current user" or "not null". I suspect you want `&&` here - in other words, incidents which haven't been resolved, and are assigned to someone other than the current user.

Comment: @JonSkeet no because there are several different users an incident can belong to

Comment: @Servy its ignoring it because incidents which have the current user field equal to the CurrentUser are showing up in the CurrentlyActiveIncidents when I specifically requested otherwise (in linq query)

Comment: @ASPCoder1450 Then the assigned tech is going to be not null, so the condition passes, as it should.

Comment: @ASPCoder1450: It's entirely unclear what you mean. Assuming that `dc` is an incident, it has a single `AssignedTechnician`, doesn't it? Do you not see how the `||` is inappropriate as it will basically *always* make that second (compound) condition true, if `CurrentUser` isn't null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you require all those records which has assigned technician != null and != current user
so you need to have And Condition

```
var CurrentlyActiveIncidents = from b in db.Logs 
join dc in db.Incidents 
on b.LogID equals dc.LogID 
where b.DateTimeResolved == null && 
    (dc.AssignedTechnician != null  && 
    dc.AssignedTechnician != CurrentUser)
```

this will give you required records